# Laravel - return variable from Form Requests to Controller

Tags: laravel

How can I return a variable from Form Requests `(App\Http\Requests)` to Controller `(App\Http\Controllers)`?

I am saving a record on function persist() on Form Requests.

My goal is to pass the generated id so that I can redirect the page on edit mode for the user. For some reason, the Controller cannot receive the id from Form Requests.

App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequests.php:

```
function persist()
{
  $business = Business::create([
    'cart_name' => $this['cart_name'],
    'product' => $this['product']
  ]);

  return $myid = $business->id;
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\MyControllers.php:

```
public function store(MyFormRequests $request)
{
   $request->persist();

   return redirect()->route('mypage.edit.get', $request->persist()->$myid);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454023/1514605

Comment: This answers your question, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964042/4132369

Comment: i think they're different, thank you.

Comment: Which Laravel version is this?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212390/laravel-middleware-return-variable-to-controller/31454023#31454023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important**

I must add that this is not the recommended way. Your FormRequest should only be responsible for validating the request, while your Controller does the storing part. However, this will work:

App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequests.php:

```
function persist()
{
    return Business::create([
        'business_name' => $this['business_name'],
        'nationality' => $this['nationality']
    ])->id;
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\MyControllers.php:

```
public function store(MyFormRequests $request)
{
    $id = $request->persist();

    return redirect()->route('register.edit.get', $id);
}
```

Comment: i saw this on the laracasts tutorial episode, so i thought that it would make my controller cleaner because the actual code has some 50 textboxes on it. should i really not put it on the FormRequest?

Comment: @kapitan No, you should put your logic in the Controller.

Comment: thank you, it's actually working when the whole saving code is on the Controller. i think ill trust you and put it back on the Controller. ill just leave the validation on the FormRequest. sigh - just when i made it work (smile). thanks @Jeffery.

Answer (score 0):

A guy name Snapey helped me:

```
public function store(MyFormRequests $request)
{
  $business = $this->persist($request);

  return redirect()->route('register.edit.get', $business->id);
}

private function persist($request)
{
  ....
  return $business;
}
```

hope this could help someone in the future.