# How to pass additional data to request inside a before middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am writing a Laravel REST API and I am using user based tokens for authentication. I am using a middleware to check and let the request pass, so far so good.

But inside the controller I wanted to access the details about the current user which results in another database calls which I don't want to afford. I am already accessing the database to validate and check the user in the middleware so I can pass the data from the middleware to the controller by injecting it into the request data. Inspired heavily by the angular's Http Interceptors which allows to do this, I wanted to it in Laravel.

I understand the request object is immutable, In Angular we achieve it by cloning the request. But I am not sure how to achieve it in Laravel, Based on my digging I attempted a solution and it seems to be working fine <s>sometimes and broken sometimes as it erases all the previous data of the request body</s>. Below is what I've done now and it sometimes erases the actual request data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Exceptions\Apex\ValidationFailed;
use App\Models\AccessTokens;
use App\Models\Users;
use App\Validators\Apex\v1\UuidValidator;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class SessionControl
{
    protected $uuidValidator;

    public function __construct(UuidValidator $uuidValidator)
    {
        $this->uuidValidator = $uuidValidator;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     * @throws HttpResponseException: if the token is not valid or expired.
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $unAuth = response(array(
            "message" => Lang::get('messages.UNAUTHORIZED-ACCESS')
        ), 401);

        if (!$request->hasHeader('access_token')
            || !$request->hasHeader('user_id')) {
            throw new HttpResponseException($unAuth);
        }

        try {
            $token = $request->header('access_token');
            $user_id = $request->header('user_id');
            $this->uuidValidator->validate(array("uuid" => $user_id));
            $access = AccessTokens::where([
                'token' => $token,
            ])->firstOrFail();
            $user = $access->user;
            if($user->getUUID($user->uuid) !== $user_id) {
                throw new HttpResponseException($unAuth);
            }
            if (!$access->expires_at->isFuture()) {
                throw new HttpResponseException(response(
                        array("message" => Lang::get('messages.SESSION-EXPIRED')), 401)
                );
            }
            //if user is root set him as super admin to hide him in records
            if($user->type === 'ROOT') {
                $user = Users::where(['type' => 'SUPER-ADMIN', 'status' => 'ACTIVE'])->firstOrFail();
                //setting root = true in request data
                $request->merge(['isRoot' => true]);
            }
            //Inject the user's session data, to avoid multiple database calls to find the user
            $request->merge(['userSession' => $user]);
            return $next($request);

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new HttpResponseException($unAuth);
        } catch (ValidationFailed $e) {
            throw new HttpResponseException($unAuth);
        }
    }
}
```

<s>Can anyone tell me what I am trying is mission impossible? I mean it shouldn't me that hard injecting a value into the controller. I think I'm missing to see something. How can it be achieved in a clean way without messing with the internals of the framework or I shouldn't be doing it?</s>

I am using Laravel 5.5, if that makes any difference.

Is this the correct way to do it, or am I making it nasty?

Comment: You could use dependency injection to pass the user to the controller, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33297725/1140065).