# Laravel how to use a variable inside middleware function outside of it

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel and in the controller I am using a  middleware function inside constructor  as following

```
  class BaseController extends Controller
   {
    //
        public function __construct(){        

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $selected_country_id = session()->get('browse_country_id')??4;
       
        return $next($request);
    });
    // end of middleware function

 //back to constructor function 
// How i can use selected_country_id here  for example 
dd($selected_country_id);
}
 }
```

my question is how to use the variable ***$selected_country_id***  outside the middleware function

Comment: duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212390/laravel-middleware-return-variable-to-controller

Comment: The middleware you wrote doesn't solve any purpose.

Comment: @nice_dev i want to use session inside constructor. how i can do that ?

Comment: @parth i want to use value inside constructor not another function

Comment: If you use it directly without middleware, what happens?

Comment: in Laravel sessions always return null in constructors

Comment: Ok, you can use sessions as is in your controller methods anyway, so you can skip trying through middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Flash it into the request with

```
$request->selected_country_id = $selected_country_id;
// or
$request->merge(["selected_country_id" => $selected_country_id]);
// or
$request->attributes->add(['selected_country_id' => $selected_country_id]);
```

And retrieve the value with

```
$request->selected_country_id;
```

Comment: how i can retrieve it inside constructor ??